# Copying a folder's children to multiple folders

Tags: shell, unix

Is there any sh script to copy all child elements in a folder to other multiple folders. What i have in mind is something like this. Folder Below will be copied.

```
/Parent/ChildDir1
/Parent/ChildDir2
/Parent/ChildFile1
/Parent/ChildFile2
```

Destinations would be like this

```
/X/a/
/X/b/
/X/c/
```

Overwriting is necessary.

Thanks

Comment: Which shell?  Do the target directories exist already?

Comment: Could you please clarify what should go where? I.e. `/Parent/ChildDir1 => /X/a`, `/Parent/ChildDir2 => /X/b` or did you mean some other mapping?

Comment: All the children will go to each /X/*/ directory

Comment: Use "cp" command in your shell script to do the desired.Please refer to help page for "cp"  details i.e. "man cp"

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you, you want to copy everything from `/Parent/` to several destination folders? So each of `/X/a/`, `/X/b/` and `/X/c/` have their own, independent copies. In that case, you could just loop over all destinations like this:

```
DESTS = "/X/a/:/X/b/:/X/c/:"
SRC = "/Parent/"
while read -d: ddir; do 
    cp -r "$SRC" "$ddir"
done <<< $DESTS
```

The extra `:` at the end of `DESTS` might be removable if you find the right invocation of `read`, I couldn't :(

Comment: That seems ok but there are app. 800 destination folders. Is it possible to use wildcards when defining destinations?

Comment: Yes, you could generate the `DESTS` variable using wildcards. For instance, if you want all subdirectories of `/X/` which begin with an `a`: `DESTS=$(find /X/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'a*' -exec echo -n {}: \;)`. (There might be a simpler way to do this, this is just off the top of my head)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to find all directories in `X` i.e. X/a, X/b, X/c etc and then recursively copy your source directory into them:

```
find /path/to/X -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec cp -r /path/to/Parent {} \;
```

If your directory list is in a file you can just read each line in the file and execute `cp`, like this:

```
while IFS= read -r dir
do
    cp -r /path/to/Parent "$dir"
done < dirs.txt
```

Comment: ok but now i realized there are some folders that i dont want to copy stuff in. is it possible to read folder paths from a file like folders.txt

Comment: @skuul yes, I have updated my answer to read directories from a file.